# Should I cover the case when service that I'm calling threw an exception even though the service is tested separately?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

While reviewing one of my colleagues PR's we got ourselves into a discussion whether we should cover the case where the service we are calling throws an exception with unit test or not. Have in mind that the service we are calling are covered by unit tests as well. I have prepared a code snippet to better introduce the topic of our discussion below:

Let's say we have an `OrderService` which returns only non expired orders. For checking order expiration `OrderService` calls `ValidationService` passing order `ExpirationDate` which does the date validation. We have written a unit test for happy path case - get order from repository, call validation service, return order and we agree that it is neccessary. However we are not sure that we should cover the case when `ValidationService` throws an exception and therefore `OrderService` throws it as well?

Arguments for covering that we could think of:

- Let's say someone adds a `try catch` block and does something with the code, i.e. if exception is being thrown returns `null`. Running existing unit tests would indicate a failure since we would expect an exception to be thrown and not `null` returned.
- Execution path when exception is being thrown is not covered.

Arguments for not covering that we could think of:

- We have an exception handling middleware that handles thrown exceptions.
- Maybe this is too defensive? If we decide to cover such case, that would mean that any other service that would be calling `OrderService` would also need to be covered by same test case.

Looking at the codebase we currently maintain we see that similar cases are not covered by such test, except when you actually do something with the exception thrown, e.g. you catch it and log the exception or rethrow some other exception.

P.S. `ValidationService` is covered by unit tests and both cases when it throws and not are covered.

```cs
public interface IValidationService
{
    void ValidateOrder(DateTime expirationDate);
}

public class ValidationService : IValidationService
{
    public void ValidateOrder(DateTime expirationDate)
    {
        if (expirationDate < DateTime.Now)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Order expired.");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderRepository
{
    Order Get(int id);
}

public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IValidationService _validationService;
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

    public OrderService(IValidationService validationService, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _validationService = validationService;
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public Order GetOrderById(int orderId)
    {
        var order = _orderRepository.Get(orderId);

        _validationService.ValidateOrder(order.ExpirationDate);

        return order;
    }
}
```

Happy path test

```cs
    [Test]
    public void GetOrderById_ReturnsOrder()
    {
        int orderId = 123;
        _orderRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Get(orderId)).Returns(new Order
        {
            Id = orderId,
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
        });
        
        var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(orderId);

        _validationServiceMock.Verify(x=> x.ValidateOrder(It.IsAny<DateTime>()), Times.Once);
        Assert.That(order, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

Test that we are not sure if it's worth to have

```cs
    [Test]
    public void GetOrderById_Throws_WhenValidationFails()
    {
        int orderId = 123;
        _orderRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Get(orderId)).Returns(new Order
        {
            Id = orderId,
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)
        });

        _validationServiceMock.Setup(x => x.ValidateOrder(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
        
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => _orderService.GetOrderById(orderId));

        _validationServiceMock.Verify(x=> x.ValidateOrder(It.IsAny<DateTime>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

We are seeking for other opinions and insights on this topic. Please feel free to share.

Comment: That's an easy test for "my code does not swallow exceptions of its dependencies" and if that is your expectation then i would test against that expectation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I will vote to close this question as it lends itself to opinion. That being said, my personal one is that you shouldn't be testing that a method throws an exception but rather how your code calling that method handles that situation. Your `OrderService` would then need to be tested for the expected behavior when the `ValidationService` throws an `InvalidOperationException`. What is it supposed to do? rethrow? Swallow and return `null`?

Comment: On a side note, why can't `ValidateOrder` return `true` or `false` instead? `InvalidOperationException` implies you did something you weren't supposed to. Passing a date for verification is exactly what the service is for. It seems pretty valid to me, not to count that exceptions used in this manner have performance implications as well.

Comment: By the way, you are wasting more time posting this question and discussing it than it would take to just write the test. Just pointing that out. :-)